# Python Division Function

Tags: python

I am working on practice homework for my computer science class and I cannot seem to figure out how to solve for the question I have been given.

Write a function that takes two numbers, one number to be divided by the second number. The function should return the number of times the second number goes into the first and the remainder. For example, if the function is sent 9 and 5, it should return 1 and 4.

Any ideas?

Codes I have Tried:

def division_function(a, b):
    first = a//b
    second = a%b
    return(first, second)

I have also tried the general division functions within Python, but that also does not seem to be working.

The website we use is a bit tricky, as we are not using Python itself.
Also, I understand the "general" Python code of division, I am just trying to find other eyes, perhaps to see where I am messing up.I have only been in this class for a few days and we have not yet gone over the material, but have already been given assignments.

Also, if this helps, I often get this error code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/unit_tests.py", line 12, in test_testdivRem
    self.assertEquals(divWithRem(9,5),(1,4))
NameError: name 'divWithRem' is not defined

Comment: What did you try? What did not work?

Comment: Code one step at a time, get each step working before you go onto the next.  If you need help *show your code*.

Comment: Please update the question with what you've already tried and what problems you're encountering.

Comment: I don't feel comfortable sharing an answer to this question even though it's easy reputation. It's a straightforward question that requires minimal python knowledge.

Comment: Check the mod `%` operator, that may be a good jumping off point for part of the question

Comment: Take a look at the `divmod` built-in function.

Comment: Since it is academic, I guess that the intention is to use a loop. You need to figure out if and how a loop could be helpful then choose a stop condition. After then, the reminder should be easy to find.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? Dividing 2 numbers? Getting the remainder? Returning multiple values? What the syntax for a function is? Google probably has the answer to each of those questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I think you need to name the function you defined `divWithRem` in order for it to work on your website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) function does exactly what you want:

```
>>> a, b = divmod(9,5)

>>> a
1

>>> b
4
```

However, if you want to define your own function, this should work:

```
def divide(n1, n2):
    quotient = n1 // n2
    remainder = n1 % n2
    return (quotient, remainder)
```

The `//` operator represents [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html), and the `%` operator represents [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) ([remainder](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Remainder.html)).

```
>>> a, b = divide(9,5)

>>> a
1

>>> b
4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def division_function(a, b):
    first = a//b
    second = a%b
    return(first, second)
```

Explanation:

def division_function(a,b) -> Indicates signature of the method, taking two parameters( a and b)

first = a//b  -> performs integer division ( divide and omit the decimal place) and store that value to a variable named first

second =  a% b  -> performs modulo operation ( divide the two numbers and get the remainder) and store that value to a variable second

return(first, second) -> this function will return a tuple with both the first and second value

Answer (score 0):

we have 5 apples and 4 persons, you know that 1 apple will remain and the 4 persons  will eat so remainder is 1 and 4 is found only one in 5
the remainder means % in python and divide 5/4 to know how many times

```
    num1=int(input("enter your first num:"))
    num2=int(input("enter your second num:"))
    remainder=num1%num2
    number_of_times=num1 / num2
    print(remainder)
    print(int(number_of_times))
```